# You do not have permission to call setDataValidation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-custom-function

I am trying to use a custom function. Whenever I try to use it as a formula from within sheets and run it on a cell it throws the error:

> You do not have permission to call setDataValidation

But when I run it from the script editor it runs perfectly fine. How can I make it work without having to click `Run` from the script editor?

Note: I prefer not to use triggers.

Comment: Are you trying to affect cells other than those it returns a value to? [Doc: Return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values)

Comment: @ocordova no. it's only for the cell on which the formula is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`SpreadsheetApp` service is read only when called with custom functions**

Ocordova has the right idea. The [article he cited](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) discusses how the `SpreadsheetApp` service is...

> Read only (can use most `get*()` methods, but not `set*())`.
>   Cannot open other spreadsheets (`SpreadsheetApp.openById()` or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()`).

If you want to be able to edit cells, you will need to call the functions from a custom menu.

Comment: I am not using `openById()` nor `openByUrl()` but using `getActiveSpreadsheet()` but I still get the error.